# Looping through two arrays simultaneously

Tags: loops

What is the best way to loop through and output the value of 2 arrays simultaneously?

---

The values of the two arrays here reference the key position of two other arrays named images and details respectively.  So the loop should not output the integer value of these arrays but the value assigned to the associated keys in the referenced arrays.

```
var imgindex = [0,1,3];
var detailindex = [2,4,6];
$(imgindex).each(function(i, o) {
    $("#row").append("<img src='" + images[o] + ".png'/><div>" + details[o] + "</div>);
} );
```

Comment: What about combining both?

Comment: Iterate through one of the arrays (using `$.each` not `$().each()`), then use the current index in the callback.

Comment: How about using `.each` twice?

Comment: does it have to be jquery.each? what about using a for or while?

Comment: Like @OmarQa said, why are you using `$.each` anyway? Just use a `for`, `forEach`, or `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `$each` on one array and use index to get elements.

```
$(imgIndices).each(function(index, elem) {
    $("#row2-detail").append("<img src='{$base_dir_ssl}img/cms/" + images[imgIndices[index]] + ".png'/><div>" + details[detailIndices[index]] + "</div>");
 });
```

Here `detailsIndices[index]` will give me the index for `details` array.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.  I guess I should have mentioned that the integers in imgIndices and detailIndices are references to key's in another array.  The other arrays are named images and details respectively.

Comment: I edited your sample because there was a missing close quotes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var imgIndices = [0,1,15,16,17,18];
var detailIndices = [3,11,2,4,10,5];
$(imgIndices).each(function(i, o) {
    $("#row2-detail").append("<img src='img/cms/" + imgIndices[i] + ".png'/><div>" + detailIndices[i] + "</div>");
});
```

Where `i` is **index** and `o` is **value**.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v94W7/)**

You have error in your code. `"` is missing. and `images` and `details` and undefined.

```
$("#row2-detail").append("<img src='{$base_dir_ssl}img/cms/" + images[o] + ".png'/><div>" + details[o] + "</div>);
                                                                                                               ^^
```